# Comparing polygons in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following array of polygons:

```
[[ 32 451]
 [ 61 451]
 [ 61 472]
 [ 32 472]]
[[ 32 473]
 [ 60 473]
 [ 60 488]
 [ 32 488]]
[[ 32 435]
 [ 61 435]
 [ 61 452]
 [ 32 452]]
[[ 30 505]
 [ 61 505]
 [ 61 525]
 [ 30 525]]
[[ 32 488]
 [ 61 488]
 [ 61 504]
 [ 32 504]]
```

Computing the width, height and area I can compare these as follows:

```
[[ 32 451]
 [ 61 451]
 [ 61 472]
 [ 32 472]] ('width:', 29.0, 'height:', 21.0) area: 609.0
[[ 32 473]
 [ 60 473]
 [ 60 488]
 [ 32 488]] ('width:', 28.0, 'height:', 15.0) area: 420.0
[[ 32 435]
 [ 61 435]
 [ 61 452]
 [ 32 452]] ('width:', 29.0, 'height:', 17.0) area: 493.0
[[ 30 505]
 [ 61 505]
 [ 61 525]
 [ 30 525]] ('width:', 31.0, 'height:', 20.0) area: 620.0
[[ 32 488]
 [ 61 488]
 [ 61 504]
 [ 32 504]] ('width:', 29.0, 'height:', 16.0) area: 464.0
```

Now what I would like to achieve is to loop over the polygons and find the one with the greatest area and set all other equal to this. How can I ahcieve something like this? My inital thought was to loop over the polygons, compute the area and store the polygon with greatest area in a temporary set and set all others equal to the one stored in the set after the loop(?). How would this go?

Answer (score 1):

Your initial idea seems correct to me. Loop over polygons, calculate area, see if the area is larger than the current area, if this is the case store the area and the index of the polygon. Here is some pseudo-code:

```py
max_area = 0
max_area_idx = -1
for idx, polygon in enumerate(list_of_polygons):
    area = compute_area(polygon)
    if area >= max_area:
        max_area_idx = idx
        max_area = area
```

In the end loop again over your array and set all `area = max_area`.